# Crop an image in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm building an image cropping system, and here is a basic simplification of the 3 elements in a view controller i organized to achieve this:

```
 @IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView! // contains the 2 elements below

 @IBOutlet weak var originalImage: UIImageView! //fit in 100% space of above container

 @IBOutlet weak var imageGrabber: UIView! //Rectangle on top of originalImage
```

So we have a container containing image originalImage. Container is resized so image occupies the entire space. Then, we have a rectangle view imageGrabber on top of the image.
The goals here are:

1) Grab rectangle coordinate from the imageGrabber, determined from its position in containerView.

2) Crop originalImage from those rectangle coordinate

So the final result, is a cropped image, corresponding to the area covered by imageGrabber.

Do you know a way to accomplish these ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly all you have to do is 
 1. Get the final frame of your imageGrabber . 
 2. Get the same frame from the containerVIew which contains the image, you can user `drawRect` method to draw the image of size as your imageGrabber.

Comment: should I use imageByCroppingToRect at any point in the process ?

Comment: You can do that as well,the important part is to get the cropped frame,once you get those frame either you can use imageByCroppingToRect to crop the image or drawImage:inRect .

Comment: thanks... and to get the frames I should investigate into drawRect right ?

Comment: No frame of the cropped area should ideally be the frame of imageGrabber,so you can crop or drawImage as the size of your imageGrabber . 

Do accept the answer if it helped you ..:)

Comment: thanks i'll try to implement this first and will get back here if/when I succeed.

Comment: hi again, i think i'm progressing. What do you think of convertRect to convert coordinates and size of imageGrabber to the CGRect I need ?

Comment: @AbhinandanSahgal: This answer would be more useful to the community if you posted the code for the solution. (I'd like to see it!)

Comment: Yes an example code would help me understand cropping as well.